# Circular motion interception problem

Tags: optimization

I'm trying to calculate the optimal speed (minimizing time) to intercept another object that is moving in the same circular path as me.
Here's the catch, there are some constraints:

- There is a mininum value for the time ($t_{min}$).
- My speed has a minimum ($\omega_{1min}$) and a maximum ($\omega_{1max}$) value.

My initial position is $\alpha_1$ and the target's initial position $\alpha_2$.

$$\Delta_0=\alpha_2-\alpha_1$$

I don't care how many "turns" each object does before the encounter. So the final difference is $2{\pi}N$. Where $N$ is any integer number including 0 and negative values.
So here is my main equation:
$$\Delta=\Delta_0-(\omega_1-\omega_2)t$$
solving for $\omega_1$ and replacing $\Delta$:
$$\omega_1=\omega_2+\frac{\Delta_0-2{\pi}N}t$$
Of course my first approach is to solve using $t=t_{min}$ and $N=0$. But what happens if the resulting angular speed is below the lower limit ($\omega_1<\omega_{1min}$) or above the upper limit ($\omega_1>\omega_{1max}$)?
Should I increase $N$? Decrease $N$? Use $\omega_{1min}$ or $\omega_{1max}$ and solve for $t$?

There are so many possibilities that I don't know which one I should I apply under each condition. I expect that the solution is some sort of iteration of steps, which is fine for me because this is going to be converted into programming code.

Notes: I don't know the relation between $\omega_2$ and $\omega_{1min/max}$, but I do know all of them are positive:

$$0<\omega_2$$

$$0<\omega_{1min}<\omega_{1max}$$

I also realize that in some cases there may be multiple solutions, in such cases I would choose the solution where $N$ is closer to zero.

Comment: I'd look at this the other way around: What's the range of possible relative distances $\Delta$ I can attain at time $t_{\mathrm{min}}$? Is there a multiple of $2\pi$ in that set? If not, how much more time will it take until going at either $\omega_{1\mathrm{min}}$ or $\omega_{2\mathrm{max}}$ reaches a point $\Delta=2\pi N$?

Comment: Thanks @aschepler! I ended up using your approach. Finding the right $N$ when I had some multiples of $2\pi$ in the $\Delta$ range was not super straight forward, but eventually I solved it.